# Start a Fragment Activity NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer

I'm using the `NaviagationDrawer` with the `Fragment`. Now in `MainActivity`, I open the various fragment but one of the lines must open an `FragmentActivity`

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new InFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new RiFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new RieFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

**I want to change the case one to a fragment activity how can i do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an intent to open in case one a `FragmentActivity`:

```
...
     case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myFragmentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        case 2:
            fragment = new RiFragment();
            break;
...
```

Comment: in that case the NavDrawer , will continue watching?

Comment: yes, in fact your are open another activity (myFragmentActivity) over MainActivity, that is still contaning the navigationDrawer.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my awful english.